# let x = (0&0xFFFFFFFF) + ~0 +1 , what is the value of x?

Tags: c, binary, hex, bitwise-operators, bit

I'm working on a c bit homework, for one of the questions it is asking me to implement logical negation without using '!'; this is what  I came up with:

`

```
(0 & 0xFFFFFFFF) // S1: 0s & ones should return 0s right?

+ ~0 +1  // S2: then to the value above I add 1 and the not value of 0 (which in my understanding is 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

`

Now in human language, S1 result: 0x0000 , S2: 0x0000 - 0 + 1
which should end up returning 1. I instead get 0. Where am I going wrong here??

Thanks in advance :)

edit:
do you think there's hope for this approach if modified? and counting the fact that I can pass a non zero number that should give me a 0 as a result. !(n) = 0 unless n ==0 then it should return 1.

Comment: The goal of "implement logical negation without using '!'" is unclear as the equation is constant.

Answer (score 2):

`(0 & 0xFFFFFFFF)` certainly forms an `unsigned 0` or `unsigned long 0` as `0xFFFFFFFF` is a hexadecimal constant that first fits into one of those 2 types. [@Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71651794/let-x-00xffffffff-0-1-what-is-the-value-of-x/71652079#comment126632706_71652079)

`0` is a *signed* 0.  `~0` flips all the bits - the result remains *signed*.  With the very common 2's complement encoding, this is a *signed* -1.

Then the addition of an *unsigned* 0 with  `~0` becomes unsigned `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0xFFFF` as -1 is first converted to an `unsigned`, etc. depending on the bit width of `int/unsigned`.

Adding 1 to that, the value is 0.  The result is *unsigned*.

---

> Where am I going wrong here?

Adding `~0` is not like subtracting `0`.

---

> implement logical negation without using '!';

This requires shifts or ifs and often implementation depended code or simply:

```
y = x == 0;
```

[Soapbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox): IMO, it is a poor assignment for a learner as it encourages implementation dependent code.  C has !` for a reason.

Comment: For unsuffixed hexadecimal integer constants, the candidate list is `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.

Answer (score 0):

> Now in human language, S1 result: 0x0000 , S2: 0x0000 - 0 + 1

`~0` is not `-0`, it's `-1`. If necessary, read up on two's complement encoding.

So your expression is:

```
(0 & 0xFFFFFFFF) + ~0 +1 =
(0 & whatever) + ~0 + 1 =
0 + ~0 + 1 =
~0 + 1 =
-1 + 1 =
0
```

Comment: The C standard does not require two’s complement. It allows one’s complement and sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: Duly noted. Read up on two's complement either way, it's the most useful one by far.

Answer (score 0):

This expression in which each operand has the type `int`

```
~0 +1
```

is equivalent to (if to use the internal representation)

```
0xFFFFFFFF + 1
```

that in turn is equal to

```
-1 + 1
```

provided that the compiler uses the 2's complement representation of integers that yields `0`.

So `S1` and `S2` are both equal to `0` and hence the result is also equal to `0`.

Comment: `~0 + 1` is not equivalent to `0xFFFFFFFF + 1`. If `int` is 32 bits, then `0xFFFFFFFF` would equivalent to `4294967295`; it would have type `unsigned long`. If `int` is narrower or wider, it would have a different number of bits set. By showing `0xFFFFFFFF`, you may be trying to say that `~0` produces an `int` with all bits set, but that is a different thing, and, if you are trying to say that, you should say that. Further, the result having value −1 relies on two’s complement, so the answer should either state that as a premise or should explain the alternatives.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wrote clear if to use the internal representation not the literal.